# Odoo 12 CE, Qweb-text report includes all HTML template code

Tags: text, report, odoo, qweb

As we know from Odoo 12 there is an option to define a report as Text, rather than PDF/HTML. I am testing with the native report Product Label (PDF), exactly as those guys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kPlOWj2Zpk . The result I am getting is a txt file, with all the HTML code from the generated template.
A partial screenshot attached https://prnt.sc/qi90cg
The installation is fresh, no 3th party modules, only Invoicing from odoo 12 itself. Only difference i see between me and YouTube guys is that i am testing on Community Version and the YouTube video clearly shows an Enterprise version.
Any suggestions why I am getting the HTML code exported as well?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used a QWEB report which does not generate HTML tags.

Take for example the two following codes:

```
<strong t-field="product.lst_price" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': product.company_id.currency_id}"/>
```

And :

```
<t t-esc="product.lst_price" t-options='{"widget": "float", "precision": 2}'/> <t t-esc="product.currency_id.symbol"/>
```

The first one will be rendred to

```
<strong><span class="oe_currency_value">68.00</span> €</strong>
```

And the second one will be rendred to

```
68.00 €
```

You can find an example at [account_zebra](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/stock_zebra/report/product_templates.xml#L4)

Comment: Thank you for the the hint and zebra link. It works, but now facing another issue :)..i need to t-esc a value under a loop. The loop has about 50 rows of code and last is t-esc. Here is a screenshot of the beginning of the loop https://prnt.sc/qjftpm Naturally we have &lf at each row, which is rendered as empty row in output txt file. And the result is a huge text file with 50 empty rows between t-esc values...How to avoid rendering &lf in output txt file, so the t-esc values are one under the other...

Comment: Try to remove line breaks.I can see only the beginning of the loop, so it should start like the folloxing `<t t-foreeach="inv_taxes" t-as="line"><t t-if="print_details > 0"><t t-if="line['index'] == 0"><t t-set=...`

Comment: That's what i did and it works...but all 50 lines of code written on a single row is completely unreadable for debugging. I have like 9000 chars long row of code :)...so if i need to add/change/remove is very hard to keep track...finally i ended up with 2 identical xml report files...one formatted where i can keep track on changes and updates, second xml report file in production, where all code is on a single row...